# How can I parametize the C library name and path calling JNA library?

Tags: java, jna

I'm working with another team who needs a C SO wrapper. I decided to develop the Wrapper using JNA.

Assuming for example that the C *.h code is as follow :

```
extern "C" CSAMPLE_API int init_function (
    unsigned            firstValue,
    unsigned            secondValue,
    void **             ouputPointer);
```

The JNA library is as follow :

```
public interface IJNALibrary extends Library {
    static final String LIBPROPFILE = "./src/main/resources/wrapper.properties";
    
        public static Properties getPropertyReader(InputStream reader) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.debug("Property reader", e);
        }

        return prop;
    }

    static String getCLibName(String propFileName) {
        // Properties file management
        String cLibName = "none";

        InputStream reader;
        try {
            reader = new FileInputStream(propFileName);
            Properties prop = IJNALibrary.getPropertyReader(reader);

            cLibName = prop.getProperty("libFileName");
            String jnaLibraryPath = prop.getProperty("jnaLibPath");
            System.setProperty("jna.library.path", jnaLibraryPath);
            logger.debug("Library Name is {}", cLibName);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.debug("Wrong library Name which is {}", cLibName);
        }

        return cLibName;
    }

    static Map<String, StdCallFunctionMapper> getOption() {
        Map<String, StdCallFunctionMapper> options = new HashMap<>();

        options.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, new StdCallFunctionMapper() {
            @Override
            public String getFunctionName(NativeLibrary library, Method method) {
                String name = super.getFunctionName(library, method);
                switch (name) {
                case "initFunction":
                    name = "init_function";
                    break;
                default:
                    name = "none";
                }
                return name;
            }
        });
        return options;
    }
    // LOADING LIBRARY
    NativeLibrary lib = NativeLibrary.getInstance(IJNALibrary.getCLibName(LIBPROPFILE));
    IJNALibrary INSTANCE = Native.load(IJNALibrary.getCLibName(LIBPROPFILE), IJNALibrary.class,
            IJNALibrary.getOption());
    
    // INIT FUNCTION
    public int initFunction(int firstValue,int secondValue, PointerByReference ouputPointer);
}
```

wrapper.properties file content is as follow :

```
jnaLibPath=./src/main/resources
libFileName=SOLibName
```

The java Sample that calls the JNA Wrapper is as follow :

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    

        int firstValue = 2;
        int secondValue = 3;
        
        PointerByReference ouputPointer = new PointerByReference();
        ouputPointer.setValue(null);

        int initReturn = IJNALibrary.INSTANCE.initFunction(firstValue, secondValue, ouputPointer);
    }
}
```

Instead of using a properties file in order to define the C librairie SO file name and its corresponding path,
I want to beable to set lib path and name through init variables that would be set by the Sample.java.
My issue is that as IJNALibrary extends jna.Library which is a java interface thus I cannot define variable attributes in IJNALibrary (only final types thus constants).
Is there a possible way doing that?
Note that we do not want to have the C SO file included in the JNA Wrapper jar file.
The goal is to be able to update the C SO file without building a new JNA Wrapper jar file (as in that case the interface between C functions and the JNA wrapper is not updated).
To be more clear I wanted to have something similar to as follow (but for sure it is not possible as IJNALibrary is a java Interface):

On JNA library side, it would be something similar to (quickly written...):

```
public interface IJNALibrary extends Library {

    String libPath;
    String libName;
    
    public static void initLibAttributes(String libPath, String libName) {
        IJNALibrary.libPath = libPath;
        IJNALibrary.libName = libName;
    }
    
    static String getCLibName() {
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", IJNALibrary.libPath);
        return IJNALibrary.libName;
    }

    static Map<String, StdCallFunctionMapper> getOption() {
        Map<String, StdCallFunctionMapper> options = new HashMap<>();

        options.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, new StdCallFunctionMapper() {
            @Override
            public String getFunctionName(NativeLibrary library, Method method) {
                String name = super.getFunctionName(library, method);
                switch (name) {
                case "initFunction":
                    name = "init_function";
                    break;
                default:
                    name = "none";
                }
                return name;
            }
        });
        return options;
    }
    // LOADING LIBRARY
    NativeLibrary lib = NativeLibrary.getInstance(IJNALibrary.getCLibName());
    IJNALibrary INSTANCE = Native.load(IJNALibrary.getCLibName(), IJNALibrary.class,
            IJNALibrary.getOption());
    
    // INIT FUNCTION
    public int initFunction(int firstValue,int secondValue, PointerByReference ouputPointer);
}
```

On Sample.java side :

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
        int firstValue = 2;
        int secondValue = 3;
        
        PointerByReference ouputPointer = new PointerByReference();
        ouputPointer.setValue(null);
        
        String libPath = "./src/main/resources"; 
        String libName = "SOLibName";
        
        IJNALibrary.initLibAttributes(libPath, libName);
        
        int initReturn = IJNALibrary.INSTANCE.initFunction(firstValue, secondValue, ouputPointer);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of detail here for what seems to be a simple question.  This line of code should already do essentially what you're looking for: `IJNALibrary INSTANCE = Native.load(IJNALibrary.getCLibName(), IJNALibrary.class, IJNALibrary.getOption());`.  The problem boils down to parameterizing a static class variable in the interface?  But you could call a static method in any class.  Also see `NativeLibrary.addSearchPath()` for a custom location per library name (string is the map key)

Comment: Indeed I created in IJNALibrary a getInstance static method which returns a IJNALibrary instance with 2 input parameters String libPath and String libFileName.
Inside getInstance method, I call `System.setProperty("jna.library.path", libPath)` and return instance by calling  `FSIGLibrary instance = Native.load(libFileName, FSIGLibrary.class, FSIGLibrary.getOption());`
In sample.java I call this static method as follows `IJNALibrary instance = IJNALibrary.getInstance("./libPath", "mylibFileName");` and then calls `int initReturn = instance.initFunction(firstValue, secondValue, ouputPointer);`

Comment: I'm still unclear exactly where your problem is. There's so much detail.  Can you clarify your post by indicating exactly what's failing to work?